# uploading derby db to the web server

Tags: java, derby, google-code

I have dynamic web project with limited functionality (name DYN_WEB) and a project that communicates with a derby db on my computer (name DATA). It correctly works on a localhost, puts and retrieves some data.

But how I upload all this (DYN_WEB project + DATA project + Database) to the google code, so that another person can download it a use?

Thanks!

Comment: Google code uses several different version control systems including svn and git. You have to use one of those.

Answer (score 0):

You could zip up your database into a zip file, then upload the zip file, and your users would then download and unzip that database on their own systems.